# c9.io stop apache to free up process.env.PORT

Tags: mysql, apache, bash, cloud9-ide

I was attempting to run both node and apache on a c9.io web server VM.  I had used the c9.io phyMyAdmin install [script](https://c9.io/site/blog/2014/11/phpmyadmin), which configures the local MySQL instance, installs then restarts apache.  phpMyAdmin can be accessed fine at `https://workspaceName-workspaceOwner.c9.io/phpMyAdmin` however, I now cannot stop apache from running, taking up the env.PORT assigned by c9.

Response from root request:

[image]

When node runs:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

My attempts at stopping the apache process:

From Tools -> Process list -> search for apache and force kill - no effect

From the terminal:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

> - no effect

```
apachectl stop
```

> httpd (pid 20190?) not running

```
service apache2 stop
```

> - Stopping web server apache2  *
>     No effect, web server response and process still exists

```
ps au | grep apache
```

> ubuntu   22910  0.0  0.0  10552   880 pts/3    S+   06:30   0:00 grep
>   --color=auto apache

```
kill -9 22910
```

> bash: kill: (22910) - No such process

```
kill -9 `ps au | grep apache | awk '{print $2}'`
```

> bash: kill: (22926) - No such process

```
killall apache2
```

> apache2(20190): Operation not permitted

As c9.io do not give su access to the VM or allow us to restart the VM does anyone have any other possible way to resolve this? I'd also like to switch between running node and apache quickly (as both isn't possible) to use phpMyAdmin as I cannot connect with MySQL Workbench.  Any assistance or advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kill the apache2 process by typing: `sudo killall -9 apache2` into the terminal. Also, on Cloud9, `apachectl start` and `apachectl stop` are the only recommended ways to start/stop the apache server.

Btw, you can restart your workspace by clicking on the stats menu item on the right and clicking the 'Restart' button in the dropdown. Did that not work for you?

To switch between the two, you can probably make a shell script to do that, but another idea could be to use apache to act as a proxy to your node app. I haven't tried this myself, but maybe the following could help:

http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah I was under the impression [sudo](https://docs.c9.io/terminal.html) was disabled. `Warning: While certain operations, like sudo, are restricted...` Restricted != Disabled. Much appreciated, I must have missed the Restart button all together.  I will absolutely give the proxy a try!